# How simple is it to parse tables from multiple XMLs into 1 generic SQL table by column order (not by column name)?

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing

One application outputs 1-5 XML files. Each XML file contains a table, and usually the tables aren't the same (different column names, different amount of columns etc)

I am trying to find out how hard/easy it is to write code that parses those XML files into 1 SQL table.

The SQL table would have let's say 20 string type columns with generic names (column1, column2 etc). And the desired way of parsing is throw the data from each XML in by column order, ignoring all names.

So if XML1 has 5 columns and 10 rows of data, and XML2 has 7 columns and 4 rows of data, the SQL table should be have data in the first 5 columns for the first 10 rows, and then in the first 7 columns for the next 4 rows. So basically like throwing each table under the other. This is repeated for any number of XMLs (might be 5+)

Thanks in advance.

XML1:

```
<Table1>
 <PLANT>
  <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
  <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
  <ZONE>4</ZONE>
  <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
  <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
  <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
 </PLANT>
 <PLANT>
  <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
  <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
  <ZONE>3</ZONE>
  <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
  <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
  <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
 </PLANT>
 <PLANT>
  <COMMON>Marsh Marigold</COMMON>
  <BOTANICAL>Caltha palustris</BOTANICAL>
  <ZONE>4</ZONE>
  <LIGHT>Mostly Sunny</LIGHT>
  <PRICE>$6.81</PRICE>
  <AVAILABILITY>051799</AVAILABILITY>
 </PLANT>
<Table1>
```

XML2:

```
<Table2>
 <food>
  <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>$5.95</price>
  <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real 
  maple syrup</description>
  <calories>650</calories>
 </food>
 <food>
  <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
  <price>$7.95</price>
  <description>Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and 
  whipped cream</description>
  <calories>900</calories>
 </food>
 </Table2>
```

SQL target table:

| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5 | Column6 | Column7 | Column8 | Column9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bloodroot | Sanguinaria canadensis | 4 | Mostly Shady | 2.44 | 031599 | Table1 |  |  |
| Columbine | Aquilegia canadensis | 3 | Mostly Shady | 9.37 | 030699 | Table1 |  |  |
| Marsh Marigold | Caltha palustris | 4 | Mostly Sunny | 6.81 | 051799 | Table1 |  |  |
| Belgian Waffles | 5.95 | Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup | 650 | Table2 |  |  |  |  |
| Strawberry Belgian Waffles | 7.95 | Light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped cream | 900 | Table2 |  |  |  |  |

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: I didn't include sample data and exact logic because I'm not asking someone to write me the code. I'm just asking how complex/simple the task is.

Comment: Your question is on a verge to get closed. Please provide a couple of XML files samples and target SQL Server table structure.

Comment: Honestly not difficult.  It's done all the time.  It just requires attention to detail while mapping columns.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I edited and included some samples. Is that sufficient?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti That's what I thought as well. Thanks

Comment: That's even easier, but why would you not want to line-up the columns?  Price is in Column5 and then in Column2

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Because the real-case example is much more complicated than what I described here and some columns will never have a match.

Comment: @Zhalam Just for fun, take a peek at  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2522626f82c3d991b24dca6995320289

Comment: @Zhalam A cleaner approach where the XML gets stored in a table  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=7feec0b708bda2d9c7b30d800280022f

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Thanks a lot for your time John, both those links look very helpful. How do I give you rep/mark as solved?

Comment: @Zhalam Don't worry about the Reps.  I just wanted to illustrate that it can be done with relative ease.   All too often TECH says it is hard or can't be done.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Again thank you. That was the purpose of my question too. The one thing that I'm not sure if I saw in your code (and my coding experience is very very limited) is the ability to deal with an unknown number of XMLs and unknown number of columns in its tables. For this i imagine there would have to be a couple of loops in there

Comment: @Zhalam No loops, CROSS APPLYs.   The technique illustrated does not care how many rows or columns... they will be transformed into column1 through column? as determined by the PIVOT.   Even if you have nested XML with variable depths, there are techniques to handle that as well.

Comment: @Zhalam In this example, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=efa4cd99a52a814b0298c26881ec3362 I create TWO functions.  Both have the same core, but one will PIVOT the results.  You may notice that I don't specify ANY XML Tags.  The key is not normalize the data into an EAV Structure.  Feel free to pass this link on to your guy.   I'm sure with a little imagination and perhaps a few tweaks, he can make it work for you.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti That's perfect. Many thanks once again!!